# GET-ADGroup, How can i pipe the last 4 of the SID into a variable?

Tags: powershell

Hope my code formatting pastes correctly, i am very new to powershell as a whole. And as i am working my way through Service Desk, i am trying to automate some of my tasks and learn powershell at the same time. I am hitting a snag with my offboarding employee script i am writing. I need to set a primary group, i have been able to add it without issue, setting it as primary is where im hitting a wall. Im doing all this in a hyper v lab on my personal device, $DisabledGroup is the distinguished name for the group, and 1135 is the last 4 of the SID. It works great if i run it with 1135 as the $GroupID, but (and i may be wrong) want to run the $DisabledGroup and check its SID, and somehow pipe the last 4 of the SID (So the GroupID) into $GroupID, but im at a loss as to how and google isnt leading me anywhere.

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity "$DisabledGroup" 
 $GroupID = "1135"
 Get-ADUser $TargetUserName | Set-ADObject -Replace @{primaryGroupID="$GroupID"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you're looking for the last 4 digits or the [last component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#security-identifier-architecture) of the group's SID. A SID may or may not end with 4 digits. I'll assume you're looking for the last component, in which case this is how you can extract it:

```
$sid = 'S-1-5-21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330-512'
$sid.Split('-')[-1] # => 512
```

This is how the code would look:

```
$adGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $DisabledGroup
$GroupID = $adGroup.SID.Value.Split('-')[-1]
Set-ADUser -Identity $TargetUserName -Replace @{ primaryGroupID = $GroupID }
```